# Postmates API - Status Code 400 - params":{"__all__":"invalid price quote"}

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, postmates

I'm trying to make a post to the `/v1/customers/:customer_id/deliveries` endpoint using firebase. I'm sending the query params from an angular application.

**Query Object**

```
{ 
  pickup_name: 'Patrick O',
  pickup_phone_number: '619-***-****',
  dropoff_name: 'Wendell And Chad',
  dropoff_phone_number: '619-***-****',
  manifest: 'Cheese',
  quote_id: 'Mc26u6TwH_qKkF',
  dropoff_address: '4606 Market Street, San Diego, CA',
  pickup_address: '1041 Market Street, San Diego, CA' 
}
```

**Response (Firebase Function)**

```
Unhandled error { StatusCodeError: 400 - {"kind":"error","code":"invalid_params","message":"The parameters of your request were invalid.","params":{"__all__":"invalid price quote"}}
...
name: 'StatusCodeError',
  statusCode: 400,
  message: '400 - {"kind":"error","code":"invalid_params","message":"The parameters of your request were invalid.","params":{"__all__":"invalid price quote"}}',
  error: 
   { kind: 'error',
     code: 'invalid_params',
     message: 'The parameters of your request were invalid.',
     params: { __all__: 'invalid price quote' } }, ...
```

I haven't encountered the error for `__all__` in the Postmates Api Docs. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Submitting the query params without the quote_id property gives me a successful response.

Comment: Originally, I took the first 4 characters off of the id from the quote object (from quote endpoint) and used that as the quote_id of the delivery query object. Kind of got the idea to do that from the postmates node package docs

Comment: Hi @PatrickOdum, can you please confirm if this solved the issue? If so, can you post an answer with a detailed explanation of what you changed to get it working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing the quote_id property from the query params

**Query Object**

```
{ 
  pickup_name: 'Patrick O',
  pickup_phone_number: '619-***-****',
  dropoff_name: 'Wendell And Chad',
  dropoff_phone_number: '619-***-****',
  manifest: 'Cheese',
  dropoff_address: '4606 Market Street, San Diego, CA',
  pickup_address: '1041 Market Street, San Diego, CA' 
}
```

I haven't tested it but I believe the quote_id property can be used but the string has to be the full quote id.

`quote_id: 'dqt_Mc26u6TwH_qKkF',` as oppose to `quote_id: 'Mc26u6TwH_qKkF',` like I had it.

*I will update the answer after verifying the latter*